# Images Not Displaying In Table

Tags: html, css

I am working on an assignment and I need to place some images in a table, which normally isn't a problem for me. Today when I added the images to the table it just displays a square border with the alt text written in it. I am pretty sure that I am pointing to the right directory.

My folder structure is:

```
Website
  css
  fonts
  html (Page with table in here)
  js
  images (Images for table in here)
```

[image: Table]

```css
@font-face{ font-family:customFont; src: url('../fonts/Balkeno.ttf'); }

* {
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 300%;
 background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

nav {
 font-family: customFont;
 font-size: 30px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 50;
}

.nav-background {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #12A7CB;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.nav-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 320px;
}

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:320px;
 width: 100%;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
 width: 100%;
 height: 320px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #5E5E5E;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#logo { 
 float: left; 
 padding-left: 100px;
 padding-right: 200px;
}

#nav {
 background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-dVtgikk-kOY/UprtswP0yGI/AAAAAAAADag/Og0DtZ8t_oQ/s1600/header+base.png) no-repeat scroll top left;     background-color: transparent;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #5E5E5E;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}

.title {
 display:none;
 color:#EDEDED;
 font-size:25px;
 width:350px;
 margin-top:6px;
 margin-left:150px;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:left;
}

.navigation li{
 list-style-image: url('navIcon.png'); 
 float: left;
 padding-right:45px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 color: black;
}

li {
 
}

.navigation a {
 font-size: 19px;
 font-family: customFont;
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #01ebfe;
} 

.navigation a:hover {
 
}

.wrapper {
 width: 900px;
 height: 1000%;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 padding-top: 100px;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

p{
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 32px;
}

p:first-letter {
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #71CAE0;
}

h1 {
 font-family: customFont;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: #12A7CB;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-family: customFont;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #12A7CB;
 text-align: left;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #D8D8D8;
}

img.logo {
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
}

img.slideshow {
 width: 100%;
 height: 480px;
}

footer {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 25px auto 0 auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.members {
 padding: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #e4f4f8;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #12A7CB;
 float: right;
}

ol.test {
 list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.members ol {
 list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.members li {
 display: list-item;
 color: #6c6c6c;
 list-style-type: lower-alpha;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

/* TABLE STUFF */

table, tr, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
 padding: 5px;
 color: #12A7CB;
 background-color: #e4f4f8;
}

td {
 background-color: #f2eded;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
}

/* END TABLE STUFF */

.video-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.video-wrapper a {
 color: blue;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.social img {
 padding-top: 32px;
 padding-right: 8px;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <!-- 
 Author: #####
 Date: 11/08/2014
 -->

 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Home - Three Doors Down</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" /> 
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
  <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/header.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <nav class="nav">
   <div class="nav-background">
   </div>
   
   <div class="nav-content">
    <img src="../images/navTitle.png" alt="Three Doors Down" id="logo" width=250 />
    <ul class='navigation'>
     <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
     <li><a href="discography.html">Discography</a></li>
     <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
  
  <header class="header">
   <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="../images/header1.jpg" alt="Three Doors Down" class="active" />
    <img src="../images/header2.jpg" alt="Three Doors Down" />
    <img src="../images/header3.jpg" alt="Three Doors Down" />
   </div>
  </header>
  
  <section>
   <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Discography</h1>
    
    <div class="disco" >
     <table >
      <tr>
       <th>
        Album
       </th>
       <th>
        Year
       </th>
       <th>
        Record Label
       </th>
       <th>
        CD Cover
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >
        The Better Life
       </td>
       <td>
          2000
       </td>
       <td>
        Universal Republic
       </td>
       <td>
        <img href="../images/theBetterLifeCover.jpg" alt="The Better Life" width="100" height="100" />
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >
        Away from the Sun
       </td>
       <td>
        2002
       </td>
       <td>
        Universal Republic
       </td>
       <td>
          <image href="../images/awayFromTheSunCover.jpg" alt="Test" width="100" height="100" />
       </td>      
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >
        Seventeen Days
       </td>
       <td>
          2005
       </td>
       <td>
        Universal Republic
       </td>
       <td>
        Cover
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >
        3 Doors Down
       </td>
       <td>
          2008
       </td>
       <td>
        Universal Republic
       </td>
       <td>
        <image />
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td >
        Time of My Life
       </td>
       <td>
          2011
       </td>
       <td>
        Universal Republic
       </td>
       <td>
        Cover
       </td>
      </tr>     
     </table>
    </div>   
   </div>
  </section>
  
  <footer>   
   <div class="nav-content">
    <ul class='navigation'>
     <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
     <li><a href="discography.html">Discography</a></li>
     <li><a href="video.html">Video</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the urls to images, they may not be correct

Comment: It's `<img src="...">`, not `<img href="...">`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed href="../images/imageName.png" to src="../images/imageName.png"

Answer (score 1):

change the code below code...

```
<image href="../images/awayFromTheSunCover.jpg" alt="Test" width="100" height="100" />
```

New code

```
<image src="../images/awayFromTheSunCover.jpg" alt="Test" width="100" height="100" />
```

**href** attr is for **links**  i.e for **a** tag. For image use **src** attr

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code. The image path is you mentioned in your HTML code is point to [this](http://stacksnippets.net/html/images/navTitle.png) link only. So check the path and make sure the images are there

Comment: The navTitle.png image is not the one I am having trouble with, it is the two in the table below that.

Comment: That's also not display. Open your page in browser and check with inspect element. You can see the image is not there.... http://stacksnippets.net/images/theBetterLifeCover.jpg returns the error 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Make sure your css and images are also there... B'Coz when open your code in browser and check inspect element, its returns 13 errors including jquery.js, style.css also 404 ERROR

Answer (score 0):

It's < img src="" >, not < img href="" >.